# Page width and container width

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm using the WordPress theme Fable by Elegant Themes. I'm also using the Elegant Themes builder. I want content to have a white background that automatically spans the width of the page but I want the content (text, titles, images, tabs, etc.) to only span 960px.

If I change the width of .container in the style sheet from 960px too 100% I get the desired effect of the white background, but the content is also at a width of 100%. If I leave it at 960px, the content is 960px and so is the white backgrounds.

If anyone is familiar with Elegant Themes that'd be helpful. I've tried numerous changes in the CSS but can't seem to figure it out. I'll temporarily take the lock of my site in progress for the next few hours so you can see what I'm talking about - jayseaconsulting.com

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
.et-additional-content{width:100%; background:#fff;}
```

Comment: Somewhat, it made the whole background white though.

Comment: that's what I read in your description "a white background that automatically spans the width of the page" so I did that. Could you be more specific?

Comment: Yeah I didn't do too good describing it lol. It's easier to see. If you go to the site - jayseaconsulting.com - the sections with a white background are what I want to span the width of the page but then I still want that image in the background to show between them.